# Unable to save product attribute issue

Tags: magento2, event-observer, rest-api

I have an observer, using this event: `catalog_product_save_after` , where I would like to assign some website ids to my product. This is my code:

```
public function execute(Observer $observer)
{
    $product = $observer->getProduct();
    $product->setWebsideIds([1,6,7]);
    try{
        $product->getResource()->saveAttribute($product, 'website_ids');
    }catch (Exception $error){
        var_dump($error->getMessage()); exit();
    }
}
```

The thing is that I am receiving the following error:
`Error: Call to a member function getBackend() on bool in /var/www/html/myproject/vendor/magento/module-eav/Model/Entity/AbstractEntity.php:1666`.
Also, the observer is triggered , when i want to create a new product via the magento API: `rest/V1/products`. Any idea, what should i do here ? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually, I gave up using the `saveAttribute` and I found a workaround, using a plugin:

```
<type name="Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface">
    <plugin name="product_save_api" type="Namespace\Module\Plugin\Api\Product" disabled="false" sortOrder="1" />
</type>
```

and the class:

```
class Product
{
    private $storeManager;

    public function __construct(
        StoreManager $storeManager
    ) {
        $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
    }

    public function beforeSave(
        ProductRepositoryInterface $subject,
        ProductInterface $product,
        $saveOptions = false
    ) {
        $extensionAttributes = $product->getExtensionAttributes();
        $extensionAttributes->setWebsiteIds($this->getWebsiteIds());
        $product->setExtensionAttributes($extensionAttributes);
    }
    public function getWebsiteIds() : array
    {
        $websiteIds = [];
        $websites = $this->storeManager->getWebsites();
        foreach ($websites as $website) {
            array_push($websiteIds, $website->getId());
        }

        return $websiteIds;
    }
}
```

I leave this post here, could be helpful for someone.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following code:

```
$product->setCustomAttribute($attributeCode, $val);
```